# Enable Today's View widget via in-app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, ios-app-extension, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

What I have done so far:

I have created a Today's widget via app extension for my containing app. Widget is working perfectly the way I want. My application has the feature of in-app purchases.

What I want:

I want the widget to not show up(even the name of widget) in Today's view unless the user don't make purchases from the containing app.

p.s
In-app purchases is working fine and I have a *UserDefault* in my Today's view controller which tells me whether user has made in-app purchases or not.

Answer (score 3):

You don't get to make that choice.

- If the today extension exists, it shows up in the list. No exceptions.
- If the user enables the today extension, it's enabled.

What you would need to do is let the today extension be displayed, but without whatever functionality your in-app purchase enables. You can't have the extension and prevent it from appearing, but you can still control **what** it shows when it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna point out that enabling widget functionality via IAP will most probably get rejected from the App Store(as it recently did for me).

Here's the message I got in Resolution Center:

> The Today Extension should provide some functionality before purchase
>   with IAP per the App Extension Programming Guide.

Comment: I was reading the guide recently, I don't think it actually says that.

Comment: Well, even if it's not in the guide, it was the reason for rejection.

Comment: Yeah, I wish they'd be more clear about submitting in the dev docs.
UPDATE: I'll add that recently I accidentally submitted an app with a placeholder string in the widget, and it was approved. I thought was disabled in the build, but I was wrong...